# Ubuntu 12.04 GNOME Terminal (3.4.1.1) Xorg 100% CPU

Tags: 12.04, xorg, 64-bit, gnome-terminal, cpu-load

after upgrading Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 (x64 arch) maximizing or resizing GNOME Terminal (3.4.1.1) windows larger cause the Xorg (1.11.3) or X process to utilize 100% CPU. Resizing smaller, moving windows or minimizing do not seem to have the same impact but by no means are snappy either.
I'm running on a Dell E6500 laptop (upgraded from 11.04) running the nvidia proprietary drivers v. 295.49 (Quadro NVS 160M) with compiz 0.9.7.8.
Other terminals such as xterm/uxterm are unaffected.

Hoping it has to do with some configuration settings but not sure where to look (nvidia/compiz/gnome/X?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out it has to do with my dual monitor setup through Nvidia's Twinview. With my external monitor disabled it does not seem to slow down.